# Logging JIRA issues using Cypress Dashboard with JIRA plugin integration

Tags: cypress, jira

Is there an automated process to automatically log all the accessibility issues(generated from a web page using cypress-axe plugin) into JIRA issue type(bug) using JIRA plugin(purchased and integrated) with Cypress Dashboard or should we manually create a bug(using Create issue button shown on Cypress Dashboard's test run failure using JIRA plugin purchased with Cypress)

Comment: I found only manual way of creating jira ticket https://docs.cypress.io/guides/dashboard/jira-integration#Creating-a-Jira-issue-for-a-test-case, but your question is clear for me